# Convert String to ArrayList<String> using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to deserialize a JSON data to a POJO.

The issue is that the list object is coming as a string, and gson gives an IllegalStateExceptioState. How can I parse the string as a list to an ArrayList using gson?

**JSON DATA**

```
{
   "report_id":1943,
   "history_id":3302654,
   "project_id":null,
   "owner_emails":"[\"abcd@xyz.com\"]",
   "message":"Array\n(\n    [name] => SOMENAME\n    [age] => 36\n    [gender] => male\n)\n"
}
```

**POJO:**

```
    public class EventData {
    
        private static Gson gson = new Gson();
    
        @SerializedName("report_id")
        public String reportID;
    
        @SerializedName("history_id")
        public String historyID;
    
        @SerializedName("project_id")
        public String projectID;
    
        @SerializedName("owner_emails")
        public ArrayList<String> ownerEmails = new ArrayList<String>();
    
        @SerializedName("message")
        public String message;
    
    
        @SerializedName("title")
        public String title;
    
        public CrawlerNotifiedEventData(){
            this.projectID = "Undefined";
            this.reportID = "Undefined";
            this.historyID = "Undefined";
            this.title = "";
        }
    
        public String toJson(boolean base64Encode) throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException{
            
            String json = gson.toJson(this, CrawlerNotifiedEventData.class);
            
            if(base64Encode)
                return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(json.getBytes("UTF8"));
    
            return json;
        }
    
        public String toJson() throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException{
            return this.toJson(false);
        }
    
        public static EventData builder(String json){
            return gson.fromJson(json, EventData.class);   
        }
    }
```

**Deserialization:**

```
EventData eventData = EventData.builder(json);
```

While deserializing i get the following error

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 252 path $.owner_emails
```

Comment: are you using any library?? like retrofit?

Comment: No retrofit, just Gson and java standard librarires.

Comment: Do you see that your JSON is misdesigned and holds an array in a string, not self, so that Gson can't map a string to a list of strings? Ask your JSON producer to produce a properly designed response and not wrap the emails field in a string. If it's not possible and you must deal with such a badly designed API, then either deserialize the field value in a later stage, or write a custom JSON-unpacking deserializer to deal with some kind of stuff (hint: use `@JsonAdapter` for the field).

Comment: @fluffy can't change the JSON data being produced. Wil look into JsonAdapter.

Comment: Valid format of array object should be: 
"message": [{"name": "Rajiv", "age": 36, "gender": "male"}]. Use regular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boxing structured data in a string where it is unnecessary is a very common design issue across different serialization approaches. Fortunately, Gson can deal with fields like `owner_emails` (but not `message` of course).

Merely create a type adapter factory than can create a type adapter for a particular type by substituting the original one and doing a bit of more work. The adapter is supposed to read the payload as string and delegate the string deserialization to the type adapter it substitutes.

```java
public final class JsonStringBoxTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private JsonStringBoxTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        final TypeAdapter<T> adapter = gson.getAdapter(typeToken);
        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public void write(final JsonWriter out, final T value) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); // TODO
            }

            @Override
            public T read(final JsonReader in)
                    throws IOException {
                return adapter.fromJson(in.nextString());
            }
        };
    }

}
```

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
final class EventData {

    @SerializedName("owner_emails")
    @JsonAdapter(JsonStringBoxTypeAdapterFactory.class)
    List<String> ownerEmails;

}
```

The unit test below will be green:

```java
final EventData eventData = gson.fromJson(json, EventData.class);
Assertions.assertEquals(new EventData(ImmutableList.of("abcd@xyz.com")), eventData);
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

"owner_emails" is curently a string as follows

```
"owner_emails":"[\"abcd@xyz.com\"]"
```

It should be

```
"owner_emails": ["abcd@xyz.com"]
```

to be considered as array. You can manually remove the quotes and parse it.

Or you can parse it using `JsonElement` in Gson

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObjectMapper from **jackson librar**y for this conversion.

Sample code of conversion::

```
public <T> T mapResource(Object resource, Class<T> clazz) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(resource), clazz);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
```

Modify the model for a **list** like::

```
 public class Reportdata{
   
   private List<String> owner_emails = new ArrayList(); 

   @JsonDeserialize(contentAs = CustomClass.class)
   private List<CustomClass> customClassList =  new ArrayList();  
   ....// setter and getter
}
```

In addition to this, while creating the ObjectMapper object you can pass or register the module/ your custom module for deserialization in object like below.

```
objectMapper.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING);
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```